# redirect to 404 wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, debian, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I setup a wildcard A record on my domain registrar. Now if a user access a missing subdomain on my domain, they will be redirected to the homepage. Currently my initial setup was this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R]
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  # more below...
</VirtualHost>
```

Any wildcard subdomain or if my IP is entered via URL will redirect to the homepage. Can I do something about this that will redirect (HTTP redirect perhaps) the wildcard subdomains to 404 page instead of to homepage?

Comment: May be you could use a PHP script to check hostname and generate a 404 error if necessary.

Comment: Probably, but what I have in mind is like a "could not find host" page. Like in any other sites. (eg. deads.google.com)

Comment: @SalmanA - why'd you deleted your answer? It's working and probably what I was looking for.

Comment: deads.google.com does not seem to work (nslookup fails). I would really like to see an example of how others are doing this.

Comment: @SalmanA - exactly, that was my point. I want to end up like that. Say in my Google Chrome, if I visit deads.google.com it returns "Oops! Google Chrome could not find deads.google.com"

Comment: OMG, that pages is built into the browser, does not come from a server :) But still, having a custom made dead-domain page is a good idea, you can tell search engines/humans that the page does not exist anymore, or it has moved permanently to a new location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your rewrite rule to this; it should fire the Apache 404 error page:

```
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

The error page can be set to a custom HTML or PHP page using the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive. While HTML pages work nicely, a PHP script allows you to do a little more.

<del>You can probably create a nice looking page on the wildcard domain, and do this instead: `RewriteRule .* /domain-doesnt-exist.php [L]` The page I mentioned above could send a 404 header in case you want search engines to ignore the page.</del>

Comment: Is this Apache 404 error page customizable? I mean can I style it? Where is it located?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument